# Обновление таблицы с помощью другой таблицы

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица **school**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и есть таблица **newemails**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Задача** - занести электронные адреса из таблицы **newemails** в соответствующие строки таблицы **school**.

Дело в том, что для решения подобных задач, я пишу отдельно приложение. Но мне кажется это можно сделать стандартными инструментами SQL.
Есть ли такая возможность?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE s
   SET s.SchoolEmail = e.SchoolEmail
  FROM school s
 INNER JOIN newemails e
       ON   s.SchoolID = e.SchoolID
```

Answer (score 0):

> Дело в том, что для решения подобных задач, я пишу отдельно
>   приложение. Но мне кажется это можно сделать стандартными
>   инструментами SQL. Есть ли такая возможность?

Такая возможность действительно есть. Добавляйте данные в обе таблицы при помощи [хранимой процедуры](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms345415%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) или сделайте [триггер](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms189799%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) на событие `insert` у таблицы `newemails`.

Однако первый способ более предпочтителен.

Answer (score 0):

Есть такая возможность:

```
UPDATE school
SET schoolemail = n.schoolemail
FROM school AS s
JOIN newemails AS n ON n.schoolId = s.schoolId
```