# Глобальное обновление таблицы данными другой таблицы

Tags: mysql

Сразу скажу, что смотрел [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/472910/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B) решение и у меня оно не работает. Ругается на FROM.
Есть две таблицы.

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`ab` (
`id` INT NOT NULL,
`ids` INT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = MyISAM;

CREATE TABLE `test`.`cd` (
`id` INT NOT NULL,
`ids` INT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

Есть данные:

```
INSERT INTO ab (id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO ab (id) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO ab (id) VALUES (7);
INSERT INTO ab (id) VALUES (8);

INSERT INTO cd (id, ids) VALUES (1, 111);
INSERT INTO cd (id, ids) VALUES (5, 555);
INSERT INTO cd (id, ids) VALUES (3, 333);
INSERT INTO cd (id, ids) VALUES (8, 888);
```

Теперь мне надо в первой таблице AB значение поля ids заполнить значениеми поля ids, но с таблицы CD по ключевому ID. Уверен, что в MySQL есть решение в одну команду. Я сам пишу на FoxPro. Там нужно командой SET RELATION TO связать таблицы. Подскажите как это делается на MySQL.

Comment: `смотрел это решение и у меня оно не работает. Ругается на FROM` ...... приведите полный текст ошибки пожалуйста, что там ругается и где

Comment: http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/from.1480405237.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
update ab
  join cd
    on ab.id=cd.id
   set ab.ids=cd.ids
```

Comment: все правильно и просто. спасибо огромное. Мне еще пришлось добавить до SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0; и после SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;

Comment: Как я понимаю, что в FoxPro эта команда не прокатит?((

Comment: @ВиталийФесюра Вы имеете ввиду для его внутренней БД ? не знаю какой там диалект SQL, во времена когда я общался в foxpro sql в нем еще не существовало. попробуйте `update ab set ids=(select ids from cd where cd.id=ab.id)` хотя не знаю есть ли там хотя бы подзапросы в set ...

Comment: спасибо Вам огромное. update ab set ids=(select ids from cd where cd.id=ab.id) отлично отработал в FoxPro. Только, как я понимаю, желательно перед этим проиндексировать ключевые поля (если размер таблицы довольно большой).

Comment: Да, для внутренней БД.

Answer (score 0):

```
update ab
join cd
  on ab.id=cd.id
set ab.ids=cd.ids
where ab.ids is null;
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]