# Mysqli копирование данных из таблицы в таблицу

Tags: mysql

Есть две одинаковых таблицы: data_tmp и data у которых есть по одной записи.

Можно ли как то скопировать все данные из data_tmp и data одним запросом? По сути выбрать все данные data_tmp и сделать апдейт в data?

Так как с таблицах очень много столбцов неудобно делать 2 запроса.

Comment: Столбцы все равно придется перечислять. а так http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/597149/

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT с1 ,с2 FROM data_tmp ') or die('error!   Записей не найдено!');

while ($rows=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO data (p1 ,p2) 
         VALUES(
       '".$rows[0]."','".$rows[1]."')")or die("Ошибка…". mysql_error()); 
                             }
```

Comment: В mysqli_query $db должен быть вроде первым аргументом.

Comment: Ну это пример классического способа двух запросов, вопрос был в том как обойтись одним запросом, без перечмсления слолбзов, если возможно.

Comment: @Юрий поправил, спасибо

Comment: @Юрий в моем понимании нужно перебрать строки, без цикла не представляю. И все же мне будет интересно понаблюдать за решением вашего вопроса.

Comment: В цикле необходимости нету, так как в таблице по одной строке, простое копирование статистики. а вот столбцов много...

Answer (score 0):

Если порядок полей идентичен, то все делается одним запросом

```
INSERT INTO data SELECT * FROM data_tmp
```

но так делать сильно не рекомендуется, т.к. при изменении порядка полей у Вас будет каша без всяких сообщений.

В чем проблема получить список полей (хотя бы и забить руками), а потом сформировать запрос

```
$fields = 'fld1, fld2, fldn';
$sql = sprintf('INSERT INTO data (%s) SELECT %s FROM data_tmp', $fields, $fields);
```

Или выполнить запрос

```
SELECT * FROM data_tmp
```

а потом, на основании [mysqli_stmt_result_metadata](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.result-metadata.php) узнать имена полей и сформировать INSERT запрос?

**UPDATE**

Если нужно обновлять записи, то тогда нужно добавить конструкцию `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` но тогда уже поля придется перечислять. Но опять таки, имея список полей ничего не стоит это сделать

```php
function upd($val) {
  return sprintf('$s = VALUES(%s)', $val, $val);
}

$fields = 'fld1, fld2, fldn';
$fld_upd = explode(',', $fields);
$fld_upd = array_map('upd', $fld_upd);
$fld_upd = implode($fld_upd);

$sql = sprintf(
  'INSERT INTO data (%s) SELECT %s FROM data_tmp ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE %s',
  $fields, $fields, $fld_upd
);
```

Comment: На сколько я понимаю INSERT добавит новую запись, а нужно обновить существующую из data_tmp в data .

Comment: @Юрий Добавил решение с обновлением