# MySQL: перенести результат запроса в другую таблицу исходя из условий

Tags: mysql, sql

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в mysql результат запроса  записать  в другую таблицу исходя из условий?

Например, есть  запрос в таблице объявлений `table1`, где мы берем определенные данные:

```
mysql> SELECT id_vendor, title_vendor, city_id, count(*) as count_vendors 
       FROM adds_table group by city_id;
```

Мы получили результат `table1`:

```
 +-----------+--------------+---------+---------------+
 | id_vendor | title_vendor | city_id | count_vendors |
 +-----------+--------------+---------+---------------+
 |        18 | Hyundai      |    3164 |        5      |
 |        19 | Honda        |    3165 |        3      |
 |         3 | Audi         |    3166 |        6      |
 |        73 | BMW          |    3253 |        2      |
 +-----------+--------------+---------+---------------+
```

Из этого результата нужно взять `count_vendors` и записать(UPDATE) в другую таблицу table2 для каждого значения `id_vendor`, где `table1.city_id = table2.cityid`.

`table2`:

```
 +----+-----------------+------------+---------+
 | id | title_vendor    | count_advt | city_id |
 +----+-----------------+------------+---------+
 | 18 | Hyundai         |          0 |   3164  |
 | 19 | Honda           |          0 |   3165  |
 |  3 | Audi            |          0 |   3166  |
 | 73 | BMW             |          0 |   3253  |
 +----+-----------------+------------+---------+
```

Результатом должна получиться таблица `table2` c обновленными значениями `count_advt`:

```
 +----+-----------------+------------+---------+
 | id | title_vendor    | count_advt | city_id |
 +----+-----------------+------------+---------+
 | 18 | Hyundai         |          5 |   3164  |
 | 19 | Honda           |          3 |   3165  |
 |  3 | Audi            |          6 |   3166  |
 | 73 | BMW             |          2 |   3253  |
 +----+-----------------+------------+---------+
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вам нужен join в предложении update. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/597149/%D0%93%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B/597158#597158  в приведенном примере вместо таблицы cd может выступать подзапрос

Comment: @Mike, А как это сделать без JOIN с помощью подзапроса SELECT id_vendor, title_vendor, city_id, count(*) as count_vendors 
       FROM adds_table group by city_id?

Comment: А чем вам не нравится JOIN ?

Comment: Кстати, ваш первый запрос получает просто количество записей в таблице по каждому городу. при этом в полях id_vendor, title_vendor он возвращает одного, случайного, вендора из данного города. Следовательно эту информацию в дальнейшем использовать нельзя ибо она ни о чем не говорит (в данном случае SQL даже не гарантирует, что id будет соответствовать названию вендора, они могут быть получены из разных записей)

Comment: @Mike, Мне кажется, что через JOIN будет намного дольше, потому что к одной таблице будет строиться другая. Например если table1= 200 000 строк, а table2 = 2 000 строк,  А через SELECT есть уже определенный сгруппированный результат и в зависимости от этого результата нужно раскидать данные.

Comment: Так вы же делаете JOIN готового, сгруппированного подзапроса. `update table2 JOIN (SELECT city_id, count(*) as count_vendors 
       FROM adds_table group by city_id) cd ON table2.city_id=cd.city_id set count_advt=cd.count_vendors`

Comment: @Mike, Мне нужно для каждого города посчитать количество марок. Я группирую и получаю по каждому городу посчитанный результат. Разве не правильно?

Comment: Правильно если соблюдены два условия: 1. в таблице adds_table не более одной записи по одному вендору в городе. 2. поля id_vendor, title_vendor получаемые в запросе более нигде не используются (вообще лучше их не получать)

Comment: @Mike Спасибо за запрос! Условие 1 соблюдается. id_vendor в любом случае получать придется, потому что по нему и по id города будет запись в другую таблицу.

Comment: Смотрите: у нас есть city_id=1, по нему в таблице adds_table есть две записи: (city_id=1, vendor=1) и (city_id=1, vendor=2). после выполнения вашего запроса у вас получится результат: (vendor=1, city=1, count()=2)   вопрос - как можно из полученной записи использовать vendor=1, ведь в таблице был еще и второй, который конечно учтен в количестве, но id которого был безвозвратно утерян ? И кстати, обратите внимание _вместо_ первого мог вернутся и второй, т.е. значение этого поля непредсказуемо и следовательно на него нельзя ориентироваться ни при каких условиях

Comment: @Mike, Вы правы, в таком  случае посчитается общее количество марок для города, но не по каждой отдельной марке. Спасибо за уточнение! Буду думать.

Comment: Так если в городе по одной марке все таки несколько записей и нужно их количество добавьте вендора в group by

Comment: @Mike Проблема в том, что если сгрупировать по маркам, то тогда city_id будет не корректным. В моем случае нужно группировать по двум полям и по городу и по маркам. Результатом будет общее количество каждой марки по каждому городу.

Comment: Ну да, я говорю _добавить_ вендора в `group by city_id, vendor_id`

Comment: @Mike, Спасибо вам большое за помощь! Попробую сделать это с помощью подзапросов!