# Как заполнить колонку внешнего ключа значениями из дочерней таблице первичного ключа в mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Как заполнить колонку внешнего ключа значениями `id` из другой таблицы?
Первое что я сделал, создал таблицу

```
CREATE TABLE my_list (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
first_name VARCHAR(20), 
last_name VARCHAR(20));
```

Затем понадобилось добавить внешний ключ `int_id` дочерней таблицы `interests`

```
ALTER TABLE my_list ADD int_id INT, ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(int_id)
REFERENCES interests(int_id);
```

Создается колонка `int_id` с значениями `NULL`

**Вопрос** -
Возможно ли заполнить колонку `int_id` в таблице `my_list` всеми значениями из колонки `int_id` таблице `interests`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытался сделать что-то вроде этого:

```
UPDATE my_list SET int_id = (SELECT int_id FROM interests)
```

Но это не работает

Например внешний ключ `prof_id` я заполнял так:

```
UPDATE my_list SET prof_id = 
CASE 
 WHEN id = 1 THEN 1 
 WHEN id = 2 THEN 2 // и т.д
END;
```

Но если в моей таблице будет 1000 записей. Это будет очень нудно заполнять. Я новичок в `SQL`, поэтому еще многого не знаю. Заранее спасибо за советы.

Comment: Вы не указали какая именно у вас БД. А в разных БД синтаксис может быть разный. И во вторых надо точно определить в какую запись какой id должен быть записан. Этого вы то же на указали.Чаще всего может использоваться update с join https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/597149/194569

Comment: На основе какого условия нужно обновить `int_id` в таблице `my_list`? Например, у записи с `id=7 (Carla)` какой `int_id` должен быть?