# UPDATE по результатам SELECT

Tags: mysql

Есть 3 связанные таблицы.

```
Order (id,user_id)
Order_list (order_id,product_id,amount)
Products(id,amount)
```

Задача найти `product_id` и `amount` в таблице `order_list` по `user_id` и `order_id`, и обновить данные в таблице `product` (для соответствующего товара увеличить его количество на полученный `amount` из таблицы `order_list`).

Не знаю понятно объяснил или нет. Простыми словами мне нужно реализовать отмену заказа. Исходные данные `user_id, order_id`. 
Но в чем вся сложность, как это сделать все в одном запросе??? Отдельными запросами + цикл, не проблема, хочу реализовать одним запросом без циклов.

```
SELECT
o.products_ID,
  o.amount
FROM orders_list o
INNER JOIN orders
ON o.orders_ID = orders.ID
WHERE orders.ID = ?
AND orders.users_ID = ?
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/597158/194569 в join конечно может быть ваш подзапрос, вместо таблицы

Comment: *мне нужно реализовать отмену заказа* Хреновая практика - по неподтверждённому заказу корректировать наличие. Наличие корректируется по факту убытия. А доступное количество просто считается как наличие минус сумма зарезервированного.

Comment: так это как-бы оформленный заказ, но не оплаченный, и человек имеет возможность его отменить, количество при оформлении убывается конечно.

Comment: Дело Ваше. Но вот когда столкнётесь со скандалом, что счёт оплачен в срок, а товару нету в наличии - вспомните...

Comment: Это учебный проект) но тем не менее хотелось бы разобраться что вы имеете ввиду. У меня система такая, человек набирает корзину, далее есть кнопка оформить заказ, при оформлении я проверяю наличие на складе, меняю количество и добавляю заказ (все в 1 транзакции). А отмена, это проверка есть ли такой заказ с ID и user_id (дабы исключить отмену чужого заказа путем изменения id, который прикреплен к кнопке). Далее если такой заказ есть, то я увеличиваю количество товаров на складе, и перевожу заказ в отмененные.

Comment: *хотелось бы разобраться что вы имеете ввиду* Любой косяк, вследствие которого переопределённые данные становятся невалидными. Пример. На складе одна пара сапог. Два юзера оформляют счета на приобретение по одной паре каждый. При резервировании для первого произошла некая программная ошибка, количество на складе не было уменьшено. Итог - один из юзеров останется босым. И слупит по суду за невыполнение условий договора поставки и моральный ущерб.

Comment: если происходит ошибка то срабатывает rollback. Делаю проверку, изменение количества и создание заказа в 1-й транзакции. Т.е при любой ошибке ни сделается ничего, количество останется на месте, заказ не будет сформирован.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Типа

```
UPDATE Order, Order_list, Products
SET Products.amount = Products.amount + Order_list.amount 
WHERE Order_list.orders_ID = Order.ID
  AND Products.id = Order_list.product_id
  AND Order.ID = ?
  AND Order.users_ID = ?
```

Comment: ПРЕВОСХОДНО!!!! Спасибо огромное, все оказалось проще чем я думал. Получается для того чтобы взять использовать значение из таблицы Order в SET (как переменную amount), то следует таблицу объявлять в UPDATE

Comment: @Алексей В секции UPDATE следует объявлять все таблицы и подзапросы, кроме коррелированных.