# Сохранить расчетное во вью значение в таблицу в mysql

Tags: mysql, view, table

Всем привет, при работе с view в mysql столкнулся с такой ситауцией:
Я создал таблицу:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS schema.table(
row_id INT(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
val1 DOUBLE,
val2 DOUBLE,
val3 DOUBLE);
```

В val1 и val2 заинсертил произвольные данные, val3 заполнил только в одной строке:

```
INSERT INTO schema.table (va1, val2) VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO schema.table (va1, val2) VALUES (3, 4);
INSERT INTO schema.table (va1, val2) VALUES (5, 6);
```

И создал вью основанную на этой таблице:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
VIEW test_VIEW
AS select
     t1.row_id as row_id, 
     if (t1.val3 is null, SUM(t1.val1 + t1.val2) OVER(), t1.val3) AS val3
   from 
     test t1
```

Сама проблема - как сохранить рассчетное во вью значение из val3 в таблицу в val3?

Comment: view от таблицы практически ни чем не отличается, так что https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/597149/194569

Comment: в таблице это можно было бы реализовать триггером на инсерт/апдейт, но на как вызывать апдейт из вашего примера при расчете вью?

Comment: А зачем это делать при каждом расчете view ? Ведь view создается только для того, что бы не писать в нескольких местах одинаковый код по получению чего либо. Причем чего то такого что легко вычисляется и что хранить вообще не нужно. Это я к тому, что выборок из view может быть много и на каждой из них что либо апдейтить в БД явно не правильно. Кажется вы пытаетесь решить какую то другую задачу, для которой не нужно view вообще

Comment: Задача состоит в том, что есть таблица и условному пользователю бд нужно видеть некоторые данные, которые являются произведением/суммой/тд значений из ее колонок. При поиске решения самым подходящим вариантом мне представилось создание вью. Но и хранить такие данные в виртуальном виде тоже считаю не очень правильным.

Comment: не понятно, зачем одна и та же сумма нужна во всех строках данных. Это больше похоже на строку "Итого" в каком нибудь отчете, которую обычно один раз показывают пользователю где нибудь в конце. И уж хранить в каждой строке данных итоговую сумму по всем строкам еще более странное решение. Если что то в БД приходится хранить более 1 раза, то с структурой такой БД точно что то не то. Если получение суммы работает медленно, то только в этом случае ее стоит хранить и хранилище это должно быть отдельной таблицей, где эта сумма будет лежать в единственном экземпляре и вестись триггерами

Comment: Да, фактически это и есть "Итого", которое рассчитывается для каждой строки. Но как повесить триггер на это "событие расчета" во вью?

Comment: Итог надо менять когда меняют данные, а не когда их выбирают из БД. так что сохраняете его в отдельной таблице и пишите триггер на любые изменения самой таблицы. Триггера самые простые - вычитаем из текущей суммы старые значения изменяемой строки и добавляем новые.